# How to dynamically render videos in a vue carousel?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, carousel, video.js, slick.js

I am working with a video carousel using [video.js](https://videojs.com/) and [vueslickcarousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-slick-carousel), these two library. The current code is as below:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <VueSlickCarousel
      ref="carousel"
      v-bind="settings"
      @beforeChange="onSlideBeforeChange"
      >
      <carousel-video
        v-for="video in visibleVideos"
        ....
      ></carousel-video>
  </div>
</template>

....
methods: {
    onSlideBeforeChange: function(currentIndex, nextIndex) {
      ...calculate lowerBound, upperBound for visibleVideos.
    },
},
computed: {
  visibleVideos: function() {
    slice from a videoArray using lowerBound and upperBound
  }
}
```

Here `visibleVideos` is a computed property. I want to increase/decrease the number of `<carousel-video>` rendered dynamically because the list is huge and can't render all of them at once.

However when the upperBound and lowerBound update is triggerd based on some condition, the internal state of VueSlickCarousel doesn't update.

The items are rendered in dom but these two class is missing in slick-list items - `slick-current slick-active`. That's why nothing is shown in the view. After that, If I click the next or previous button provided by VueSlickCarousel, it removes the whole component from dom.

Before updating upperBound and lowerBound

[image]

After update of upperBound/lowerBound

[image]

How can I fix this? Or is there any other library or way to efficiently render video.js videos in a carousel? Any similar implementation or opensource example will also be equally helpful.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help or suggestion.